# TSQL Select TOP and Distinct from one table into a TEMP table

Tags: t-sql

I have the following table:

```
Data        nr1 nr2 nr3 nr4 nr5 nr6
2020-09-12  6   15  36  42  67  78
2020-09-10  46  48  67  78  80  87
2020-09-08  23  27  28  31  69  89
2020-09-05  7   14  27  56  72  83
2020-09-03  16  17  38  39  68  84
2020-09-01  10  22  28  45  48  71
2020-08-29  1   3   35  42  55  61
2020-08-27  37  49  52  53  75  87
2020-08-25  15  24  31  70  83  84
2020-08-22  7   12  45  47  73  87
2020-08-20  7   17  30  39  41  67
2020-08-18  13  22  28  58  65  77
2020-08-17  5   9   26  62  77  79
2020-08-13  4   5   49  57  66  75
2020-08-11  7   9   38  68  78  80
2020-08-08  6   16  22  55  58  83
2020-08-06  21  37  40  46  69  80
2020-08-04  5   19  21  25  45  82
2020-08-01  4   14  17  18  26  45
2020-07-30  4   15  19  26  28  55
2020-07-28  23  45  49  71  80  82
2020-07-25  18  30  42  70  78  80
2020-07-23  10  29  37  49  56  57
2020-07-21  4   34  46  54  55  62
2020-07-18  18  33  49  76  80  84
```

I have to do the following task:

1. Select into a #TEMP table with only one column DistinctNumbers all distinct numbers of the above table because some numbers in the above table might be repeated across rows and columns.
2. Select into another #TEMP table all numbers in the range from 1 to 99 which are not in the original table.

What is the best way of accomplishing these two tasks?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, please read the guidelines in the [tsql tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Also, do you need the first temporary table for anything else? because you don't actually need it to get the second task...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should unpivot original table first

1.Unpivot original table into #temp table

2.Now you have all numbers in one column

3.Use while between 1 and 99 and insert counter into #RESULT table where not in #temp(unpivoted table)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(num) num INTO #TEMP_DISTINCT_NUMBERS FROM ORIGINAL_TABLE UNPIVOT ( 
    num
    FOR PivotColumn IN (nr1,nr2,nr3,nr4,nr5,nr6)
) AS UNPIVOTE_TABLE

CREATE TABLE #RESULT(NUM INT)
DECLARE @COUNTER INT =1;
WHILE(@COUNTER<=99)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #RESULT SELECT @COUNTER WHERE @COUNTER NOT IN (SELECT num FROM 
#TEMP_DISTINCT_NUMBERS)
    SET @COUNTER=@COUNTER+1
END
SELECT * FROM #RESULT
```

Comment: Don't use `while`. Instead, use a tally table. For more information, [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop.](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
;WITH tally
AS (SELECT 1 AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1
    FROM tally
    WHERE num < 99)

SELECT DISTINCT tally.num
FROM tally
    LEFT JOIN
    ( SELECT num FROM @dataset --your dataset
          CROSS APPLY (VALUES (nr1),(nr2),(nr3),(nr4),(nr5),(nr6)) AS B (num)
    ) AS dataset
        ON tally.num = dataset.num
WHERE dataset.num IS NULL
```

Code above:

1. Create [tally] recursive common table expression with sequence from 1 to 99
2. Left join tally with your unpivoted dataset ...

test here: https://rextester.com/YEB57637